# Different behaviour dependent on if statement construction

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, if-statement, windows-phone-8

I'm a little confused with a small pice of code - I created my own solution to [the problem asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140171/how-to-add-an-extra-space-after-every-fourth-character-in-the-textbox) - on KeyUp event I perform some check ups and then add a space or remove a character:

```
private void myTextbox_KeyUp1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   string text = myTextbox.Text;
   if (text.Length > 3)
   {
      if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Back)
      {
         if (text.Length % 5 == 4) text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1); 
      }
      else if ((text.Length - (text.Length / 5)) % 4 == 0) text += " ";
   }
   myTextbox.Text = text;
   myTextbox.SelectionStart = text.Length;
}
```

The code works just fine. But if I only change the interior if statement to something like this (combine two if statements):

```
if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Back && text.Length % 5 == 4)
   text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
```

The code stops working when I have more than 10 characters and then try to delete, I'm not able to delete the tenth character (space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because, by combining the 2 if statements, you go into the else if, thus adding a space

`10 - (10/5) % 4` does equal 0, so add a space.

Comment: I must say that sometimes I surprise myself (and sometimes from the bad side) - the answer to this question is obvious. I've just missed that the program adds the second space after deleting the 11th character. It turns out that leaving the problem aside for some time may be a very good idea. Thanks.